# AvqueuePlayer not working from IOS 8.1 to 8.3 but working perfectly from IOS 8.4

Tags: ios, iphone, avqueueplayer

I am using avqueuePlayer to play videos its not working from IOS 8.1 to 8.3 but work perfectly on IOs 8.4 onwards.

Comment: fullscreenAVPlayeLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];

    _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    fullscreenAVPlayeLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    
    
    fullscreenAVPlayeLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
   
    [_containerView.layer addSublayer:fullscreenAVPlayeLayer];
    [self.view addSubview:_containerView];
    [self.view  bringSubviewToFront:_sliderView];

Comment: where avPlayer is queue and which is property in fullScreenViewController.when I navigate to fullscreenViewController from firstViewContoller I set firstView avQueuePlayer property to fullsckreenviewcontoller avQueuePlayer(i.e avPlayer).